# SonicWall - gateway: trying to access the website via local ip - links in page not working

Tags: iis, asp-classic, sonicwall

So, below is the url I am trying to load. It is a classic ASP website powered by IIS.

https://gateway.xxxxxxxxx.com/ is the gateway through which the site is accessed. We are using Sonicwall.

https://gateway.xxxxxxxxx.com/go/http://192.168.1.196/default/default.asp

The above page loads, but the links and images in the page are not working. See below:
[image: images not loading]

Eg:If we have contact.asp file in the same folder('default'), the page that the browser navigates on clicking the link is

https://gateway.xxxxxxxxx.com/images/contact.asp

Throwing a page not found error.

At the same time, the links in CSS work with no problem.

Eg CSS style for : background-image: url(https://gateway.xxxxxxxxx.com/go/../images/../images/bg.gif);

It translates to https://gateway.xxxxxxxxx.com/go/http://192.168.1.196/images/bg2.gif

The above link actually works.

Not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: What kind of "Connection Refused" error? Show a full screen shot please. Also check IIS log files to see what status code/substatus code was recorded.

Comment: If this question isn't a duplicate then [edit] it and explain why instead of posting a [new duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68767183/iis-connection-refused-but-on-changing-local-ip-address-of-the-user-it-is-fi).

Comment: Do they get connection refused when connecting via VPN or are they getting it in the browser?